# Call to a member function getRealPath() on string when uploading image from url in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have one CSV file that is use to upload product in my site. So there I have image_url but when I try to upload the CSV the product gets added but the image is not uploaded. I'm using cURL to get the image from the url but it is not giving the **UploadedFile Instance**, So I think that could be the problem. So Can anyone give me any solution. Following is my code:-

```
public function import_product(Request $request)
    {
        $attributes = $request->all();
        $path = $request->file('products_csv')->getRealPath();
        $data = \Excel::toArray('', $path, null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::TSV)[0];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if($key == 0) continue;
            $checksku = $this->product->checksku($value[1]);
            if($checksku == 1){
                $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'SKU must be unique.', 
                    'alert-type' => 'error'
                );
                return redirect('/products-section/import-view')->with($notification);
            }
            if($value[4] < 0){
                $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'Price must be a positive number', 
                    'alert-type' => 'error'
                );
                return redirect('/products-section/import-view')->with($notification);
            }
            if($value[5] < 0){
                $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'Cost must be a positive number', 
                    'alert-type' => 'error'
                );
                return redirect('/products-section/import-view')->with($notification);
            }
            if(!filter_var($value[6], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
                $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'Stock must be a positive integer', 
                    'alert-type' => 'error'
                );
                return redirect('/products-section/import-view')->with($notification);
            }
            if($value[2] < 0){
                $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'Shipping cost must be a positive number', 
                    'alert-type' => 'error'
                );
                return redirect('/products-section/import-view')->with($notification);
            }
            $product = $this->product->create([
                'title' => $value[0],
                'sku' => $value[1],
                'price' => round($value[4], 2),
                'cost' => round($value[5], 2),
                'stock_level' => $value[6],
                'description' => '<p>' . $value[11] . '</p>',
                'description_short' => '<p>' . $value[12] . '</p>',
                'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'supplier_id' => $attributes['supplier_id'],
                'brand_id' => 1,
                'status' => 1,
                'taxable' => 0,
                'shipping_cost' => round($value[2], 2),
                'shipping_type' => $value[3],
                'special_teamwear_category' => $value[7] == 'on' ? 1 : 0,
                'message_artwork' => $value[8] == 'on' ? 1 : 0,
                'extra_info' => $value[10] == 'on' ? 1 : 0,
                'is_strike' => $value[9] == 'on' ? 1 : 0,
                'is_deals' => $value[13] == 'on' ? 1 : 0
            ]);
            ProductNew::saveproduct($product->id);
            $product->categories()->create(['category_id' => $attributes['product_categories']]);
            $url = $value[14];
            $extension = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $im = ProductImage::create(['product_id' => $product->id]);
            $path = 'product/' . (int)($product->id / 5000 + 1) . '/' . $product->id;
            $image_name = str_slug($product->title) . "-" . $im->id . "." . $extension;
            // $file = file_get_contents($url);
            // file_put_contents()
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            $file = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $imageInfo = getimagesizefromstring($file);
            $width = $imageInfo[0];
            $height = $imageInfo[1];
            if($width > config('const.image_size.product.width') && $height > config('const.image_size.product.height')){
                $notification = array(
                    'message' => "Image must have dimensions:". config('const.image_size.product.width').' x '.config('const.image_size.product.height') .'px', 
                    'alert-type' => 'error'
                );
                return redirect('/products-section/import-view')->with($notification);
            }
            $file_saved = Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs($path, $file, $image_name);
            $im->path = $path;
            $im->name = $image_name;
            $im->copied = $file_saved;
            $im->save();
        }
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'All of the products imported successfully.', 
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
        return redirect('/products-section/products/')->with($notification);
    }
```

I get the following error :-

[image: error coming while uploading]

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I am using the below code instead of **putFileAs**

```
file_put_contents("http://outsourcingit.asia/clubmart_storage/storage/$path", $file);
```

But I'm having this error:-

[image: error from file_put_contents]

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files) has some examples where they are using `put()` when they have the content in a variable, instead of `putFileAs()`. Maybe try that?

Comment: I was using file_put_contents instead but I was having an error. check my edited question

Comment: If you want to save a file using `file_put_contents()`, you need to pass the local file path (`/path/to/file`), not an URL. Why not try the `put()` method instead?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can I use ```Storage::disk('public')``` inside file_get_contents??

Comment: I'm not really getting what you're trying to do there, but since you already have the file contents in a variable (`$file` which contains the result of the curl request), you could try `Storage::disk('public')->put('imagename.jpg', $file);`. I don't know if that would work, but reading the docs, it seems possible.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The problem is that this image will save in another different folder which is not in the project root folder, it is outside of it.

Comment: Then do `file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/folder/foo.jpg', $file);`. The issue with the `file_put_contents()` you tried earlier was that you're passing in a URL as the file name. It needs to be a local file path.